# How to loop nested arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

VERY new to Ruby and coding in general.  I'm trying to loop through two dimensional arrays but can't figure it out. Here's what I have:

--Use a loop to print out each person on separate lines with their alter egos.

--Bruce Wayne, a.k.a. Batman

```
people = [
  ["Bruce", "Wayne", "Batman"],
  ["Selina", "Kyle", "Catwoman"],
  ["Barbara", "Gordon", "Oracle"],
  ["Terry", "McGinnis", "Batman Beyond"]
]

index = people[0][0]

first_name = people[0][0]
last_name = people[0][1]
hero_name = people[0][2]

4.times do
  puts first_name + " " + last_name + "," " " + "a.k.a" " " + hero_name
  index = index + 1
end
```

It does print the first line but then raises an error:

```
Bruce Wayne, a.k.a Batman
# `+': no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)
```

Comment: `"," " "` – I consider that advanced Ruby ;-)

Answer (score 6):

In ruby we don’t use loops by index, like `for` and family; instead we iterate on collections:

```
people =
  [["Bruce", "Wayne", "Batman"],
   ["Selina", "Kyle", "Catwoman"],
   ["Barbara", "Gordon", "Oracle"],
   ["Terry", "McGinnis", "Batman Beyond"]]

people.each do |first, last, nick|
  puts "#{first} #{last}, a.k.a #{nick}"
end
```

or

```
people.each do |first_last_nick|
  *first_last, nick = first_last_nick
  puts [first_last.join(' '), nick].join(', a.k.a ')
end
```

Comment: Do we [concatenate strings](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#string-interpolation) via `+` in Ruby? ;-)

Comment: @Stefan copy-paste is a pure evil :) I _always_ do `join` as in the second example, to handle `nil`s with `compact` instead of silly `if`s. Fixed btw.

Answer (score 2):

Your code produces error because you assign a String to index

```
index = people[0][0]
```

and then you use it to count with

```
index = index + 1
```

You could have used

```
index = 0
```

and

```
index += 1
```

A more Rubyesque way would be to enumerate the array and print it like this

```
people.each do |person|
  puts "#{person.first} #{person[1]}, a.k.a #{person.last}"
end
```

Which gives

```
Bruce Wayne, a.k.a Batman
Selina Kyle, a.k.a Catwoman
Barbara Gordon, a.k.a Oracle
Terry McGinnis, a.k.a Batman Beyond
```

Storing the parts in a variable improves readability but lenghtens the code which in turn diminishes readability, the choice is yours..

As an alternative you could name the indices or decompose like mudasobwa suggests.

```
Firstname, Lastname, Nickname = 0, 1, 2
people.each do |person|
  puts "#{person[Firstname]} #{person[Lastname]}, a.k.a #{person[Nickname]}"
end
```

Comment: Ever more Rubyesque would be to decompose `person` instead of using indices :)

Comment: @mudasobwa suggested `people.each do |fn, ln, hn|` _instead_ of indices.

Comment: @mudasobwa yep, is better, I like yours more, BTW I used indices OR decompose, so I also changed 'The most' in 'A more' :)

Comment: Good explanation. Another problem is that `index` is never used in the OP's code to access the array so it would have produced the same output 4 times.

Comment: @mudasobwa even more *Rubyesque* would be to build a `Person` object that knew how to present itself  and a `People` class to contain them :) (and a *Soylent Green* factory to decompose them)

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work:

```
4.times do |character|
  puts people[character][0] + " " + people[character][1] + "," " " + "a.k.a" " " + people[character][2]
end
```

But iterating in ruby is done as answered by others.
This is a version using a block `{}` instead:

```
people = [["Bruce", "Wayne", "Batman"], ["Selina", "Kyle", "Catwoman"], ["Barbara", "Gordon", "Oracle"], ["Terry", "McGinnis", "Batman Beyond"]]

people.each { |character| puts "#{character [0]}, a.k.a   #{character [1]} #{character [2]}" }

#=> Bruce, a.k.a   Wayne Batman
#=> Selina, a.k.a   Kyle Catwoman
#=> Barbara, a.k.a   Gordon Oracle
#=> Terry, a.k.a   McGinnis Batman Beyond
```

In general to loop through nested arrays:

```
people.each do |character|
  character.each do |name|
    puts name
  end
end
```